# creating vector in loop for file names in R

Tags: r, text

I have different text files about 400. Their names are text1, text2, text3... text400.

I want to create a vectors that is collection of these texts. Since, I have 400 texts, so I do not want to write all of their names.

I need to do something like:

```
file1 <- c(text1, text2, text3...text100)
file2 <- c(text101, text102, text103... text200)
```

Instead of writing all the text names how can I create these file1 file2 with writing in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste` with `rep`:

```
files <- paste0("text", rep(1:100))
```

From here you could use an apply function on `files` to do something on, e.g. read, each file.